# How to copy all files in all directories with specific filename to one destination?

Tags: command-line, files, terminal, file-copy

Let's assume that I have these files:

- /1/tEst.mp4
- /1/Test.mP4
- /1/subdirectory/TEST2.mp4
- /1/.20181106Test2.mp4

How can I copy all of these files into /2/Videos with a single command line?

All files that end with “mp4” and have “test” inside the name should be included. **Case-insensitive, if possible.**

I could use the file explorer to search for all files named “test” and filter by video, but is there any way to do it from the terminal?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Your answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems doable in bash:

```
set -o nocasematch dotglob globstar
cp /1/**/*test*.mp4 /2/Videos/
```

Comment: Are those `set` options shell specific? Not everyone uses `bash`.

Comment: As I led with, I assumed bash for this solution. I'm sure there's a clever zsh solution, though!

Answer (score 1):

Tested with below command and it worked fine

```
find /location_from_where_files_need_be_copied -type f -iname "Test*.mp4" -exec cp -t /targetlocation {} \;
```

Comment: The question gave the starting location and destination; I think your answer would be more value/useful with those included. Also, I don't think "2" is a requirement for the filename - it says "ends with mp4 and contains test"